# Android - Wrong layout direction when switching RTL vs LTR many times

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left, android-databinding

When I switch my app language between EN and AR (during runtime) the views behave correctly by moving from the LTR to the RTL but when I start stressing the app by switching languages many times the layout direction become missy and I get RTL elements when the app is supposed to show LTR elements. Sometimes the layout direction is not refreshed anymore.

As workaround I have to set the layout direction programmatically for those views. `binding.spinner.setLayoutDirection(LocaleUtil.isRtl(this) ? View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL : View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);`

Do you have any idea please ? I am trying to avoid this kind of workaround :( If it is possible to rely entirely on the Android UI rendering.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine a user who will switch language many times and then returning to app on every change :)

But, anyway, if Android is not able to recreate your activities correctly you always can do it manually by setting *"android:configChanges"* in *AndroidManifest.xml* for your activities and then listening for *onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)* method in such activities:

In **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="layoutDirection">
```

In **Activity** for which you set *android:configChanges*:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
        // change directions for you views to RTL
    } else {
        // change directions for you views to LTR
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, actually it is better than my workaround which is triggered on the `onCreate` method .. but it still setting the layout direction programmatically that I am trying to avoid. Anyway if I cannot find another alternative I will accept your answer :)

Comment: You are welcome :) But, honestly, I think it will be much more better and easier just to convince you testers (or yourself) that this is just another Android bug and do nothing with it. Because this is a bug really: after changing configuration which is not set in configChanges Android must recreate activity and all its fragments according to new configuration. It will be better because more workarounds = more strange code = more potential bugs in you code (and yes, yes, happy testers%)). Anyway, wishing you good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

make sure that supportsRtl="true"

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@drawable/news"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```