# Hebrew localization

Tags: android, localization, hebrew

I am using localization for Hebrew language So I have different folders for each language.
Both activities XML files are sync great with the values XML.
English working with the English string and hebrew works with the hebrew strings.
I have on some issue when using the hebrew **string.xml**
if I am adding ==> **:** to the hebrew word is switch all the characters

It is like if you will put in English
ABC:
you will see it CBA:

```
<string name="fullname">שם מלא</string>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Can you check the encoding of the XML file? It is at the bottom right of Android  Studio. Is it `UTF-8`?

Comment: UTF-8
I have also tried to add to the string.xml 
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="iw">
or
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="he">
Both cases did not help

Comment: You probably have to switch your layout Views from LTR to RTL.

Comment: I have this on the Manifest     android:supportsRtl="true"

Comment: Or should I need to do this code change per activity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644936/android-wrong-layout-direction-when-switching-rtl-vs-ltr-many-times

Comment: Or per **layout**, as I suggested (xml instead of Java). You choose. But leave the `supportsRtl=true` in the Manifest. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html